# Why does the image move in reverse direction to drag moves?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am testing this code on an emulator. When I drag the cursor to the right, the image goes to the left and vice versa.
I replaced `srcOffset` with `dstOffset` and the code worked as expected, i.e the image moves in the same directions as the cursor. I think on a LTR system like mine the origin is at the top left and y goes down and x goes right from there.
Here is the code:

```
@Composable
fun PointerInputDrag() {
    val image = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.vacation)
    var x by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }
    var y by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)

        ) {
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                            x += dragAmount.x
                            y += dragAmount.y
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                drawImage(
                    image = image,
                    srcOffset = IntOffset(x = x.roundToInt(), y = y.roundToInt())
                    )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have found out: `srcOffset` says that the new origin moves relative to itself